# how to call the function and display the result from tpl file in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I need to display product favorite count and some other functionalites in product detail page (product.tpl page).

But i am new to prestashop.so i am unable to find the where i declared function and i dont how to call the function form tpl file.

Here i write product favorite count code

```
public function favcount($id_product)
    {

         $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM `ps_favorite_product` WHERE  `id_product`='.(int)$id_product.;


        $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql);
        return  $result['count'];
    }
```

in which place i can insert the above code and how to call from product.tpl file

any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do it in the ProductController. First you need to override it. For this create (or use the existant) `/override/controllers/front/ProductController.php`. You can use your function in the `initContent()` method:

```
/**
 * @see ProductController::initContent()
 */
public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();

    // you can place your favcount method inside the class and use it
    $favCount = $this->favcount($this->product->id);
    // then assign the variable to the template
    $this->context->smarty->assign('favcount', $favCount);
}
```

Then in your template you can call the variable with: `{$favcount}`.